# Windows Phone TextBox retains autocorrect suggeston after being cleared

Tags: silverlight, textbox, windows-phone, autocorrect

I have a TextBox in an app:

```
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" Name="MessageText" InputScope="Text" />
```

And the following code wired up to a button:

```
private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // lots of code...
    MessageText.Text = "";
}
```

When the button is pressed, the TextBox is correctly cleared, but the softkeyboard's autocorrect suggestion is not, as if the last word typed into the textbox before clearing it was still there.

If the keyboard is closed and then opened again, the suggestions work fine.

What is the right way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could focus off the textbox (set focus to page) and then focus textbox back. It works and doesn't blink or something (at least in my testing).

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
    Focus();
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The autocorrect suggestions are handled by the system and can not be reset from an application. The only way to clear these suggestions is to go to the keyboard settings.

Comment: I don't want to remove the suggestions, I just want the suggestions to not be maintained when the textbox is cleared.